# Reheating boiled eggs for scotch eggs

Tags: food-safety, eggs, cooking-time, sous-vide

I recently boiled a duck egg for 7 mins and then immediately placed into iced water, where I let it sit for 10 mins.

I then proceeded to place the cold egg into a water bath set at a temperature of 145°F (63°C) for 2 hours.

I then removed the egg from the bath and made a [scotch egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_egg)

The egg was still runny after frying (which was fantastic). Will reheating the egg in the water bath be safe as it is above 140°F (60°C)?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the combination of time and temperature, when you decide whether it is safe or not. Baldwin recommends a 135°F / 57°C water bath for at least 1 hour and 15 minutes to pasteurize a chicken egg. Therefore 63 degrees in two hours should be safe even though the egg is a little larger.